Alexa skill error "callDirectiveServiceAWS is not defined"
I am using ask-cli version 2.30.7 and node version 20.18.0 running on MacOS Sonoma 14.6.1.
I am able to build and deploy with no errors, but when I test the skill using either the VSCode simulator or lambda test in aws console I get this error:
"errorType": "ReferenceError",
  "errorMessage": "callDirectiveServiceAWS is not defined",
  "trace": [
    "ReferenceError: callDirectiveServiceAWS is not defined",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:1558:1)",
    "    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)",
    "    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)",
    "    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)",
    "    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)",
    "    at _tryRequireFile (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1002:37)",
    "    at _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1052:25)",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1081:22)"
  ]

I cannot find a single hit on this when surfing the web, and I haven't a clue how to fix it.
